# How to monitor phone calls from computer?

Tags: monitoring, telephony

Is it possible to monitor,record,block,etc  phone calls of my home telephone from my computer? I really need this kind of thing because im getting calls from bad people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. For this you need a software that works as a PBX (e.g. asterix) and a FXP card or device (e. g. Cisco/Linksys/Sipura SPA3102).

Answer (score 1):

Agreed -- PBXes come standard with all the features you might want. In addition, they are totally programmable, so they can support the most complex implementations. You'll pay a premium for this flexibility, but in many cases the price difference between PBX systems and less adaptable solutions will be smaller than you might expect.

They are just one of the great choices in the [latest telephone systems technology](http://www.phonesystemprices.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google Voice if you live in the US. It provides all this functionality.